# Dot Net Core application, hosted on IIS, crashes when the system restart

Tags: iis, .net-core, dll, runtime

I have created a .NET core 5.0 project and published it. Then I hosted it on IIS. Whenever the system restarts, my application crashes. Logs after crashing are as follows:

```
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initializing logs for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\5.0.6\aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll'. Process Id: 3364.. File Version: 15.0.21113.6. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: dc5e11abdb05b322f4b74b3afbcfb352fe984b2e.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Waiting for initialization
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving hostfxr parameters for application: '.\FaxApi.exe' arguments: '' path: 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Known dotnet.exe location: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Process path '.\FaxApi.exe' is not dotnet, treating application as standalone or portable with bootstrapper
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking application.dll at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\FaxApi.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Checking hostfxr.dll at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll found app local at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\hostfxr.dll', treating application as portable with launcher
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Resolving absolute path to hostfxr.dll from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] hostfxr.dll located at 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Parsed hostfxr options: dotnet location: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe' hostfxr path: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll' arguments:
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[0] = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\dotnet.exe'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Argument[1] = 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\.\FaxApi.dll'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_HTTPAUTH=windows;anonymous;
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting environment variable ASPNETCORE_IIS_PHYSICAL_PATH=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Loading hostfxr from location C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\host\fxr\5.0.6\hostfxr.dll
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Initial Dll directory: '', current directory: 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting dll directory to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Setting current directory to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Managed application exited with code 0
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting shutdown sequence 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Clr thread wait ended: clrThreadExited: 1
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/FaxApi' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '0'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Canceling standard stream pipe reader
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping in-process worker thread
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Stopping CLR
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Event Log: 'Application '/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/FaxApi' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely' 
End Event Log Message.
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] InvalidOperationException 'CLR worker thread exited prematurely' caught at D:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\inprocessapplication.cpp:432 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Failed HRESULT returned: 0x8007023e at D:\workspace\_work\1\s\src\Servers\IIS\AspNetCoreModuleV2\InProcessRequestHandler\dllmain.cpp:131 
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting app_offline monitoring in application 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\FaxApi\'
[aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll] Starting file watcher thread
```

Application is able to start if I recycle the pool or if I restart IIS. Crashing occurs only if the system restarts.

I am using hosting bundle 5.0.6.

OS Name: Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Version: `6.3.9600 Build 9600`

IIS pool configurations are in the following link:
[IIS pool configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47ze6.png)

Comment: Check if this thread helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60750270/net-core-3-1-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure
Also, have you installed the .net core 5 hosting bundle